# Unable to use "alternatives" key when creating Cloudera parcels

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

I tried to use the "alternatives" key in my parcels.json.  However, Cloudera's parcel validiator kicked it out with:

==> Unrecognized field "scripts.alternatives". Recognized fields are "[defines, _defines]"

My parcel.json file is:

```
{
  "schema_version": 1,
  "name": "Runtime",
  "version": "2",
  "setActiveSymlink": true,

  "depends": "",
  "replaces": "MATLAB_Runtime",
  "conflicts": "",

  "provides": [
    "mine"
  ],

  "scripts": {
    "defines": "env.sh",
    "alternatives": "alternatives.json"
  },

  "packages": [
    { "name"   : "Runtime",
      "version": "2"
    }
  ],

  "components": [
    { "name"       : "mine",
      "version"    : "2",
      "pkg_version": "2",
      "pkg_release": "2"
    }
  ],

  "users":{},

  "groups":[]
}
```

The json validates fine without the "alternatives" key.

The schema for parcels.json is described in [One Engineer’s Experience with Parcel](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/07/one-engineers-experience-with-parcel/).

And the validates.json contents are described in [The alternatives.json file](http:////github.com/cloudera/cm_ext/wiki/The%20alternatives.json%20file)

Answer (score 2):

Accordingly to this: https://github.com/cloudera/cm_ext/wiki/The-parcel.json-file

> Scripts
>   Currently, there is only one script that can be specified and used by Cloudera Manager, although that may change in the future.
>   defines: This script is sourced into the environment of each process that the parcel affects (based on the tags). Even if a parcel doesn't require any environment variables to be defined, this script must be provided (the script itself can be empty).
>   The 'defines' script does the real work to make a parcel's contents accessible to processes. This is a substantial topic, discussed [here](The Parcel Defines Script).

There can be only `defines` option inside `scripts` block.
`alternatives.json` file, accordingly to this (https://github.com/cloudera/cm_ext/wiki/The-alternatives.json-file) is optional and will be silently consumed by scm agent.

Use validator (https://github.com/cloudera/cm_ext/tree/master/validator) with `-a` option to make sure your file is correct.

`-a,--alternatives-json <FILE>     The alternatives.json file to validate`